# AWS can not delete RDS cluster in inaccessible-encryption-credentials-recoverable state

Tags: amazon-web-services

My Aurora cluster used a KMS key to encrypt. A few days ago I scheduled to delete that key. Now the database is in an `inaccessible-encryption-credentials-recoverable state`.

I want to remove the cluster, however, it failed to delete the matter I used the console or AWS CLI.

I have recovered the KMS key. How can I delete the Aurora cluster?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You aren't billed for storage of an RDS cluster/instance in this state according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/accessing-monitoring.html, but I have found working with this state that the only way to delete the instance is to request AWS Support to delete it for you.